# Windows does not remember hidden network

Tags: windows-8, wifi-configuration

Every time I loose connection to my wifi, which is hidden, windows 8 forgets the connection and I have to enter in the data(SSID and pass). It's very annoying as the password is rather long and case sensitive. I've never had issues with win7 doing this.

Is there any way to stop windows from forgetting the network? (It's my home wifi and when I go out and use another wifi or disable the wifi by the hardware switch is when it seems to forget).

Comment: Open1X http://sourceforge.net/projects/open1x/?source=navbar may be help)

Answer (score 1):

When setting up a new WiFi connection to an Access Point that does not broadcast an SSID, there is an option in the Wizard labeled "Connect even if the network is not broadcasting". You should ensure this option is selected. This should allow you to re-connect even if you hardware disable/enable.